# Data error with Curve fit confidence bounds

Tags: regression, modeling

I have a fundamental question on doing experiments:

I curve fit my data $(V, \phi)$ to the curve: $V = B\cos^2(C-\phi)+A$ so I can find C, the polarization plane of the beam relative to my polarizing lens.

I have uncertainties associated to $(V, \phi)$, and they are not constant.

In Matlab, the curve fit tool generates the 95% confidence bounds for the fitted curve.[image]

So, how do I combine the 95% confidence bounds of $C$ with $\delta V$ and $\delta \phi$?

(So that I can get $C +- \delta C$.)

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve with this "combination"?  On the face of it, the confidence interval reported for $C$ communicates uncertainty in its estimate, so what is the distinction between what you're asking and what this confidence interval represents?

Comment: It looks like you're performing nonlinear regression. I doubt that will have been set up to correctly deal with an error term in the x-variable.

Comment: Lets say $V$'s uncertainty is $\delta V$ and similarly with $\phi$.
How do I represent the error term in the confidence interval.

Or at least, given the initial uncertainties, what is the final 'error term' of C?